# Spilting a large list of string and creating a list of the results

Tags: python, performance

I have a large list of strings. Each string has a number of segments separated by a ";":

```
'1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20;1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72;'
```

I want to split each string by the ";" and save the resulting list.

I am currently using:

```
player_parts = []

for line in playerinf:
    parts = line.split(";")
    player_parts = player_parts + parts
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why the `pandas` tag?

Comment: Vaishali, a huge list of strings after being seperated by ";"

Comment: Please *show us* your desired result, after you show a complete example input. (I believe what you show is just one string in your "large list"). Your description is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can try [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and unpacking a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

lines = ['1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20;1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72;', '2,3,34,56,-2134,0.50;2,4,7,2125,-3408,0.56;']
parts = list(chain(*[line.split(';')[:-1] for line in lines]))

parts
# ['1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20', 
#  '1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72', 
#  '2,3,34,56,-2134,0.50', 
#  '2,4,7,2125,-3408,0.56']
```

I added a `[:-1]` to drop the last empty element of the `split(';')`.  If however you need that empty element, just remove `[:-1]`.

Since `chain` runs on compiled code it should be much faster than the python interpreter.

The run time for 10000 lines are:

```
using chain: 0.34399986267089844s
using your method: > 240.234s     # (I didn't want to wait any more)
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know list comprehensions are always a good approach if speed is important.

```
player_parts = [line.split(';') for line in playerinf]
```

Comment: That returns a list of lists, but the OP's current solution is a flattened list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you do `player_parts = player_parts + parts`, you're combining two lists into a new list and assigning that list to `player_parts`. That's very inefficient. Doing `player_parts.extend(parts)` would greatly improve performance, since it's adding the contents to the end of the original `player_parts` list.

---

However, it looks like you may be adding some empty strings to the `player_parts` list. So let's see if there's a better way.

It sounds like you have a file like this:

```
1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20;1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72;
1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20;1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72
1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20;1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72;
```

And you want this result:

```
['1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20', '1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72', '1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20',
 '1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72', '1,2,23,17,-1006,0.20', '1,3,3,2258,-1308,0.72']
```

So this should work:

```
f = open('infile', 'r')

player_parts = []

for line in f:  # For each line in the file
    for segment in line.split(';'):  # For each segment in the line
        if segment.strip():  # If the segment has anything in it besides whitespace
            player_parts.append(segment)  # Add it to the end of the list
```

---

If you're comfortable with comprehensions, you can do this:

```
f = open('infile', 'r')

player_parts = []

for line in f:
    player_parts.extend(segment for segment in line.split(';') if segment.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Cyphase